# Express server file download with comma (",") in filename

Tags: express, encoding

I have an express server where files can be downloaded. The controller looks like this:

```
export const downloadFile = async (req, res, next) => {
  // ... get path and filename from req

  const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(path);

  const filenameUriEncoded = encodeURI(filename);

  res.setHeader('Content-disposition', `attachment; filename*=UTF-8''${filenameUriEncoded}; filename=${filenameUriEncoded}`);
  res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
  res.setHeader('Content-length', size);

  fileStream.pipe(res);
}
```

This works well but when `filename` contains a comma (",") Chrome can not download the file (shows error) while other browsers (FireFox and Safari) download well.

For example the filename `Colors - blue, green.pdf` is encoded to `Colors%20-%20blue,%20green.pdf`, so the comma is not encoded at all.

My Questions:

- what's the reason why Chrome can't handle this and other browsers can?
- are there other characters that can cause problems like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `encodeURIComponent` if you want to encode the comma too.

```
const filenameUriEncoded = encodeURI(filename);
```

As per the Chromes inability to download files with commas - [this](https://answers.nuxeo.com/general/q/d8348e07fe5e441183bae07dfda00e40/Comma-in-file-name-cause-problem-in-Chrome-Browser) is a know issue.